# Threshold error inside our CSOM code even when using RowLimit

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have the following code inside a .net console application, to get 4999 items from a custom list and add them inside a list named `customerLiveOrderAllItems` to implement paging, as follow:

```
var omsWeb = context.Site.OpenWeb("HRManagement");
context.Load(omsWeb);
context.ExecuteQuery();
var customerLiveOrderAllItems = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ListItem>();

List customerliveorderlist = omsWeb.GetList(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/CustomerLiveOrder/");
CamlQuery query1 = new CamlQuery();
string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name ='CustomerOrderAlert'/><Value Type='Choice'>No</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>{1}</RowLimit></View>", "0", "4999");
ListItemCollectionPosition position = null;
                do
                {
                    context.Load(context.Web, item => item.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    ListItemCollection collListItem10 = omsWeb.GetList(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/CustomerLiveOrder").GetItems(query1);
                    context.Load(collListItem10,
                            items => items.Include(
                            item => item.Id,
                            item => item["OrderLiveDeliveredDate"],
                            item => item["CustomerOrderAlert"]
                 ),items => items.ListItemCollectionPosition);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();/// this will raise the exception
                    
                    query1.ListItemCollectionPosition = collListItem10.ListItemCollectionPosition;

                    foreach (ListItem listItem in collListItem10) /
                    {
                        customerLiveOrderAllItems.Add(listItem);
                    }

                }

                while (query1.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);
```

Currently the list have around 11,000 records. but when the run the code, I will get this error:

> List exceeds threshold limit

on `context.ExecuteQuery();`. So why is this happening even though I define the row limit to be `4999`. Any advice?

The only thing which worked for me is to remove any filtering inside the CAML, as follow:-

```
string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><RowLimit>{1}</RowLimit></View>", "0", "4999");
```

although in my case the `CustomerOrderAlert` column is indexed..

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you find a reason for this strange behaviour?